# Perfect forwarding in operator[]

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

```
template <typename Key, typename Resource>
class ResourceHolder {
    std::unordered_map<Key, std::unique_ptr<Resource>> resources;
public:
    Resource& get(const Key& key) const {
        if (auto resource = resources.find(key); resource != std::end(resources)) {
            return *(resource->second);
        }
    }

    inline const Resource& operator[](Key&& key) const {
        return get(std::forward<Key>(key));
    }
};
```

I am trying to learn move semantics and I am wondering about my usage of `std::forward` inside `operator[]` - is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, this usage is not correct. What you want is to take your `key` value as a forwarding reference, like so:

```
template <typename T>
const Resource& operator[](T&& key) const;
```

Then, you can perfectly forward `key`. This may be confusing, but let's look at why this is necessary. Say `Key = int`. What does the `operator[]` look like when we instantiate the template?

```
const Resource& operator[](int&& key) const;
```

Notice that we are taking an r-value reference here, not a forwarding reference. What you want is a forwarding reference, which due to template deduction and reference collapsing evaluates to the proper type when instantiated.

In your example however, the value of perfect forwarding is lost as you only have one `get` function which takes a const reference. In this use case, I don't think anything but a const reference `operator[]` is useful.

Comment: So this is fine for templated functions,but i suspect you don't actually want this to be templated separate to the class value for `Key`.

Comment: You can't have perfect forwarding without a function template.